# Can an alert noise be made when a download is completed using Firefox in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, downloads

When I click to download something on Ubuntu 20.04 using the Firefox browser, an arrow shows up in the browser showing the time required to download and says if the download has completed successfully or failed.

In addition to that, can I have Firefox make an alert noise to signal me that the download is complete?

I can't explain well what I mean, so please be specific if you ask me any questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox doesn't offer this feature out of the box, and I can't find conclusive information if it ever did. But there are extensions you can try out.

One possibility is [Download Sound](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-sound/). According to the description, it

> plays a sound or utters a text using speech synthesis when a download is completed.

Another way to go might more full-fledged download tools like [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). This extension at least used to offer an audible signal, I'm not sure whether current versions still do.

I haven't tried either of those myself, but the descriptions seem worth a look. If you browse through the [extension catalog](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/), you'll probably find other candidates as well.